# An error occurred during installation in Ubuntu Server 22.04

Tags: system-installation, subiquity

I have an old laptop and I'm trying to install Ubuntu Server 22.04 on it. I want to host some game servers and potentially other things. I got through everything with no real road bumps except when trying to connect to the wifi which I couldn't get to work. I caved in and used Ethernet which is the better option either way, but after doing everything instead of the install screen I got this error screen. Does anyone know what it means?

[image]

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "old laptop"? With some hardware specifications, it may be possible to recognise an issue.

Comment: Same issue with Wifi, Eth or no network. I'm using an XPS13, which I was able to successfully install UB server 22.04 only a couple of days ago. Same USB, now doesn't work, error same as your screenshot.